# Add self one-to-many association using other fields except 'id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, self-join

I have a model `Product`, I want to implement self association on these two fields `channel_advisor_product_id`, `parent_product_id`. But when I call `Product.last.child_products` it takes its `id` instead of `parent_product_id`

```
belongs_to :parent_product, class_name: 'Product', primary_key: "channel_advisor_product_id"

has_many :child_products, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: "parent_product_id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the issue is resolved by adding the `primary_key` and `foreign_key` 
on both associations `parent` and `children`. Now the id is excluded and `self association` is working fine for my provided columns.

> belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Product', primary_key:
>   "channel_advisor_product_id", foreign_key: "parent_product_id"
>   has_many :children, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key:
>   "parent_product_id", primary_key: "channel_advisor_product_id"

Answer (score 1):

Are you using rails console?

If "yes" type exit and "rails c" again, then in console:

```
Product.last.child_products
```

and you`ll see if the query uses "**id**" or "**parent_product_id**".